# Problems with camera untity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Hi,
I've recently had a problem, I wanted to add the posibility to look on the sides with character camera in 3rd person, but it seems like after introducing it, the rest of the code seems to be ignored, like the beggining can be deleted and the rest is still working, although I think it shouldn't. It might be a bit messy, but does anyone know what's wrong?**

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Camera : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform ObjectToTrack;
    public Vector3 delta;


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.LookAt(ObjectToTrack);

        var trackedRigidbody = ObjectToTrack.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        var speed = trackedRigidbody.velocity.magnitude;

        var targetPosition = ObjectToTrack.position + delta * (speed / 20f + 1f);

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.smoothDeltaTime * 3f);

    }


    float cameraAngle = 0f;
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)) cameraAngle += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        var quaternionX = Quaternion.Euler(0, cameraAngle, 0);




        var positionX = ObjectToTrack.position
            + quaternionX * delta;




        transform.position = positionX;



        transform.LookAt(ObjectToTrack);
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-30f, 0, 0);


    }




}
```

Comment: I think you code is fine, but you are overriding the values like setting value of transform.position

Answer (score 0):

Update is called [after](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) fixed update(s) and so you're setting the position then overwriting it.

I would suggest changing this line

```
var positionX = ObjectToTrack.position + quaternionX * delta;
```

To

```
var positionX = transform.position + quaternionX * delta;
```

Or, more concisely just

```
transform.position += quaternionX * delta;
```